# Laravel Eloquent Relationship for lookup table

Tags: laravel, one-to-one, eloquent-relationship

I have a model named Item and a model named Unit
I am trying to make an inventory system

the table for Item model is
items
id
name
description
location_id
count
unit_id
type_id
provider_id

and for Unit model
Units
id
name
description

in Item model I have this public function

```
class Item extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    public function unit() {
        return $this->belongsTo('Unit', 'id');
    }
}
```

and in the Unit model

```
class Unit extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'units';

    public function items(): \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Item', 'id');
    }
}
```

and checking the DB logs I find laravel SQL is

```
select * from "units" where "units"."item_id" = $1 and "units"."item_id" is not null
```

when I do this in tinker

```
$item = App\Models\Stock\Item::find(1);
$item->unit
```

How do I go around this and tell laravel to send an SQL like

```
select * from "units" where "units"."id" = $1 and "units"."id" is not null
```

where the id value will be that of the item ?

thanks in advance

Martin

Comment: I just learned this is a 'lookup table' matter, so I changed the title

Comment: I just updated my models with methods I found in a blog talking about this, but still will not work

Comment: Take a look at this: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent#primary-keys. Laravel assumes that your table PK is 'id', but you can explicitly set your own column name.

Comment: Actually I did set it explicitly. I updated my methods so that key 'id' is used but no luck

Answer (score 0):

well... I was testing this in tinker. I was changing the models but did not restart tinker

apparently it is required to restart tinker to test after changing models